# Creating a topic with bbp_insert_topic shows up on two forums

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

This is my scenario,

I create a private Forum of type category , then I create two public forums to type forum which are the children of that category forum.  I get a nice category level organization, when I click on the url,

Home/  Forums/  Private: DummyCategory.

But when I click on one of the forums ::  Home/ Forums/ Private: DummyCategory/  DummyForum1

all the posts that do not belong to that forum shows up. It means if I post in DummyForum2 or 1 or any forum, when I click Home/ Forums/ Private: DummyCategory/  DummyForum1 , all the posts show up.

It can’t be by design ? Is this a bug ?  Most likely some settings need to be changed in the bbpress I suppose , any idea ?

Just for additional details I am using code to add into the forum. I can get the parent child relations between the forums displayed properly, the insertion of the topic goes to the right parent forum. But then that bug shows up.

```
if (!function_exists('bbp_insert_topic')) {
            require_once '/includes/topics/functions.php';
        }

        echo "All fine here ??? Did it reached ";
        $forum_ID = $selectmyID;
        $terms = array(bbp_get_topic_tag_tax_id() => $key_pieces);
        // The topic data.
        $topic_data = array(
        'post_parent'       => $forum_ID, // forum ID of Projects  hard coded
        'post_status'       => bbp_get_public_status_id(),   // Subscribed users can see this
        'post_content'      => $my_content,
        'post_title'        => $slug,
        'comment_status'    => 'open',
        'menu_order'        => 0,
        'tax_input'         => $terms  
        );

        // The topic meta.
        $topic_meta = array(
        'forum_id'    => $topic_data['post_parent'],
        'reply_count' => 0
        );

        // NOTICE! Understand what this does before running.
        $post_id = bbp_insert_topic($topic_data, $topic_meta);
        bbp_stick_topic($post_id , true);                         // Making it super sticky !


        echo "The post id returned is " . $post_id;
        echo "Sucessfully inserted the post" . $slug . " programmatically !!!!";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this: I just changed from

```
 bbp_stick_topic($post_id , true);   // Making it super sticky !
```

to this :

```
bbp_stick_topic($post_id , false);   // Making it sticky !
```

Super sticky pastes the topic at the top of every forum that was the problem. See my interaction on [bbpress forums](https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/creating-a-topic-with-bbp_insert_topic-shows-up-on-two-forums/).